# Have GraphicsLayer working but now need to put it in or convert to FeatureLayer (JavaScript)

Tags: layers, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have a GraphicsLayer working for "Regions" and the corresponding popup template information for the staff within each region (below).

```
        function fillRegionMarkers() {

            // Create a symbol for drawing the point
            var markerSymbol = {
              type: "picture-marker",  // autocasts as new SimpleMarkerSymbol()
              url: "https://SomeUrl/map-pin-16.png",
              height: "14pt",
              width: "14pt"
            };

            // Create Graphic Layer
            var gl = new GraphicsLayer({ id: "RegionPoints" }); 

            //outside loop: REGIONS
            $.each(arrRegions, function(idxRegion, elementRegion) {

                // First create a point geometry
                var point = {
                  type: "point",  // autocasts as new Point()
                  longitude: elementRegion.Longitude,
                  latitude: elementRegion.Latitude
                };  

                var DCODCEInfo = "";

                //inside loop: DCO/DCE STAFF
                $.each(arrDCODCE, function(idxDCODCE, elementDCODCE) {

                    if (elementRegion.Id == elementDCODCE.Region.Id) {
                        //Should never be null, so no need for... if (elementData.lat && elementData.lon)
                        //lat and long should never be both 0, so no need for... if (elementData.lat != 0 && elementData.lon != 0)
                        DCODCEInfo += "Position: " + elementDCODCE.Position + "<br/>" + "POC: " + elementDCODCE.StaffInfo + "<br/><br/>";
                    }
                })      

                var template = {
                    title: "<div style='font-size:12px;text-style:italic;font-weight:normal;'>(<a href='https://SomeUrl/FEMA_Regional_Map.jpg' target='_blank'>All Regions Map</a>)</div><br/>Region: " + elementRegion.FEMARegion + "<br/>Location: " + elementRegion.Location,
                    content: [{
                        type: "text",
                        text: DCODCEInfo
                    }]
                };

                // Create a graphic and add the geometry and symbol to it
                var pointGraphic = new Graphic({
                  geometry: point,
                  symbol: markerSymbol,
                  popupTemplate: template
                });

                //layer.add(pointGraphic);
                gl.graphics.add(pointGraphic);
            })

            //Add graphics layer to map
            map.add(gl);
        }
```

The problem is a URL feed with a FeatureLayer is now being used to show Regions (below).

```
    var featureLayer = new FeatureLayer({
      url:
        "https://SomeUrl/Regions/FeatureServer/0",
      title: "Regions",
      visible: true

    });

    map.add(featureLayer);
```

This FeatureLayer does not have the DCO/DCE staff or pinned lat/long locations like the GraphicLayer has. So how do I add or convert this GraphicLayer to a FeatureLayer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the main difference here is that instead of creating the `graphic.PopupTemplate` from scratch and building up that string, you can use [popupTemplate](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-FeatureLayer.html#popupTemplate) instead, and the associated [createPopupTemplate()](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-FeatureLayer.html#createPopupTemplate) function. [Example here](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/intro-popuptemplate/index.html).

Comment: ...combined with adding to View instead of map. Thank you.